# How to add text image and price labels to added widget with add_widget option in python?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, kivy

I have 3 kivy files, main.kv, shop.kv and item.kv, then main.py.
shop.kv is included in the main.kv and i want to add_widget(item()) class to be able to generate item() with different text price and item name and image ; in my case, the item() widget is RoundedButton.

so please, please help.

main.py

```
import sys
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder

kv="""
<RoundedButton@Button>:
    background_color: (0,0,0, 0)
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: (.4,.4,.4,1) if self.state=='normal' else (0,.7,.7,1)
            # rgba: (0,0,0,0.1) if self.state=='normal' else (0,.7,.7,1)
        RoundedRectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            radius: [30,]
"""
class RoundedButton(Button):
    pass

Builder.load_string(kv)

class Item(RoundedButton):
    pass
        
class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
         
        
        Item_scrn_grid = self.ids.shop.ids.item_gd
        for i in range(2):
            btn = Item()
            Item_scrn_grid.add_widget(btn)
            
            """ 
            i want to add two texts (price and item_nam) on the each item() added widget in the loop
            """
        
class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()

if __name__=='__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

shop.kv

```
#:include Item.kv

<Shop@BoxLayout>:
    id: shop_win
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 5
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        ScrollView:
            GridLayout:
                id: item_gd
                orientation: 'tb-lr'
                size_hint_y: None
                cols: 2
                spacing: 5 
                size_hint_x: 1
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        size_hint_y: None
        height: 20
```

item.kv

```
<Item>:
    id: item_gd
    text: ""
    background_normal: ''
    size_hint_y: None
    height: 195
```

main.kv

```
#:include Shop.kv

<MainWindow>:
    id: main_win
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ScreenManager:
        id: main_screen
        Screen:
            id: shop_screen
            name: 'shop_screen'
            Shop:
                id: shop
```

Comment: Can you change the MySQL part to make to make available a copy/paste on your code please.
I think I can help you but I don't get this none working part which has nothing to do with your kivy problematic. :)

Comment: I have removed MySql part,,      i want to use the Item() add_widget's self ids in item.kv file 'item_name and item_px' to be able to change label texts in each returned Item() widget in the loop, please help out

Comment: Okay, now I see what you want, I never use dynamic stuff on the .kv, it fits more with python. Maybe @john-anderson https://stackoverflow.com/users/7254633/john-anderson can help you out on this one. KV is a limited format useful for simple instructions. It makes your difficult stuff (like dynamic stuff) more visible in your python files. KV is made for easy and space taking stuff like simple UI. :)

Comment: In your code you are adding 10 `Items` to the `GridLayout`. Do you want to make the same change to all 10? If not, then you need to have a way to determine witch `Item` you want to modify.

Comment: John, please help me show me, how i can modify only 2 items, with the code,, because honestly it's really stressing me,, because am failing to figure it out right or if there could be a better way please help me out with the modifying my code. Please

Comment: How do you decide which 2 of the 10 should be modified?

Comment: I have edited the code, please review if you can run it on pc, you will see exactly what i want. Am sorry am bothering much.